# Sitecore 10.3 Installation failed due to SQL Server connection

Tags: xconnect, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I am trying to install `Sitecore 10.3` instance on `Windows 11`. But I am getting the SSL error while `xConnect` is trying to connect to SQL Server. Error is

```
[ XConnectXP0_CreateShardApplication... : InvokeSqlcmd ------------------------]
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
[TIME] 00:04:25
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `"Encrypt": "Optional"` to 4 occurrences of InvokeSqlcmd in `xConnect-xp0.json` file and run the installation.

[image]

Reference: http://navansitecorenotes.blogspot.com/2023/06/windows-11-pro-sitecore-101x.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `"TrustServerCertificate": true`, in 4 places in `xconnect-xp0.json` (and in 1 place in `sitecore-XPO.json` if you are using `Azure SQL` ) as mention in the @Sumit answer:

Also, in SSMS check the Trust server certificate checkbox

[image]

Hope this will help.